# Basic DNN with highly imbalanced dataset -- network predicts same labels

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I will try to explain my issue at a high level, and I hope I'd be able to get some better understanding of the ML behind it all.
I am working with aggregated features extracted from audio files, so each feature vector is of size (1xN). The output would be a single sentiment label, Positive, Neutral, or Negative. I mapped these to 2, 1, 0 respectively (the labels are discrete by design, but maybe I could make it continuous?)

The dataset I am using is 90% neutral, 6% negative, and 4% positive, and I split these into train/dev/test. I wrote up a basic DNN in PyTorch, and have been training using CrossEntropyLoss and SGD (with nesterov momentum). The issue I am running into is that the network, after seeing only ~10% of the data, starts to predict only netural labels. The class weights converge to something like

```
tensor([[-0.9255],
        [ 1.9352],
        [-1.1473]])
```

no matter what 1xN feature vectors you feed in. I would appreciate guidance on how to address this issue.
For reference, the architecture is

```
DNNModel(
  (in_layer): Linear(in_features=89, out_features=1024, bias=True)
  (fcs): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=512, bias=True)
    (1): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=256, bias=True)
    (2): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=128, bias=True)
  )
  (out_layer): Sequential(
    (0): SequenceWise (
    Linear(in_features=128, out_features=3, bias=True))
  )
)

def forward(self, x):
    x =  F.relu(self.in_layer(x))
    for fc in self.fcs:
        x = F.relu(fc(x))
    x = self.out_layer(x)
    return x
```

Not sure if NN actually makes sense -- could it be the relus between each hidden layer or the bias? Or something else?

Reposted from Stack Overflow here, since this forum is more appropriate: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433774/basic-dnn-with-highly-imbalanced-dataset-network-predicts-same-labels)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51433774/781723, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/35807/8560.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  Also, re-posting your question when you already got an answer there and some suggestions on how to proceed, without acknowledging that, discussing whether it meets your need, or trying those suggestions doesn't seem like what we're looking for.  You should try those things first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross-posted

Comment: @SeanOwen my bad for cross-posting -- is there a way to keep this question and mark the other one as off-topic instead? I will avoid doing so in the future, but I believe that my question is more relevant to data science than programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A neural network is probably a perfectly reasonable approach here. But this is an extremely unbalanced dataset and you're going to have to handle that somehow.

The network is learning that the best way for it to reduce the loss is to always guess neutral - if you were taking a standardized test and you realized that you'd get 90% right if you always guessed 'C', you certainly wouldn't answer 'A' and 'B' in equal measure.

There are a few standard ways to deal with this, and probably depend on how big your dataset is (how many examples 6% and 4% come out to be):

1. Oversample the minority classes to even things out (so you'd show the net the same example of the positive / negative classes multiple times for every time it saw each neutral example)
2. Undersample the majority class (only show the net a random subset of the neutral samples during each epoch)
3. Set a class weight / sample weight - proportionally weight down the contribution to the loss function by examples of the majority class.

I'd probably try 3 first because it's super easy. Check out the [documentation of the Cross Entropy Loss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss). It takes a tensor of weights as a parameter and weights the classes according to the entries in that tensor. So just say the positive (4%) class gets weight 1, negative(6%) gets 2/3, and 90% gets 2/45 (if I did the math right...).

That would even out the total contributions of each class in the dataset. Hopefully you'll see better results that way. You'll probably want to look at precision / recall to evaluate the results (because random guessing gets you 90% if you're using accuracy).

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response! So for CrossEntropyLoss in PyTorch, is there a way to make it optimize for precision/recall? I know for non-NN models in sklearn you can set the scorer to be f1,acc, etc; would something similar apply here?

Comment: I don't know that 'optimizing' for precision / recall is the right way to think about it, because there can be tradeoffs that are subjective depending on the application - for example, when testing for cancer, we'd want our model to have more false positives than false negatives, and ideally no false negatives; this is because while a false positive is really scary and stressful, it's ultimately not too harmful.  A false negative means that real cancer will go untreated, which is a potentially fatal situation.  So in this case, we want to prioritize the recall of the 'cancer' class to be 1.

Comment: Anyway, what I'm saying is that what 'optimum' for precision and recall is can be subjective.  Do you care more about positive sentiment? Negative? It might depend on what you're doing.  I just thought it'd be a good idea to look at those metrics because it'd be easy to train a model and say "Oh, 91%! Not bad!", when the model that just guesses neutral every time gets 90%.  One thing that I've done in the past is use sklearn's classification_report.  If you use the value of the highest softmax output of your network as the prediction probability, it'll print out a very digestible summary.

Comment: Alright, so "optimizing" is problem-dependent. I found that the sentiment/emotion detection literature tends to use unweighted average recall (UAR), so I could prioritize that metric?

Comment: Also, with the weights you suggested, I ran my network again, and I am now getting some other predictions. The test UAR is 42%, which is only slightly better than random chance (33.3%), but at least something. Next I'll give the over/undersampling methods a shot.